# Correct way of moving to another .SKS file

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a game where I have two scenes: FarmScene and WoodScene. 
Each scene has a .SKS file and a .swift file - one to design, and one to code. 
I've managed to move from FarmScene to WoodScene like this:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "WoodIcon" {
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
                if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "WoodScene") {
                    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                    // Present the scene
                    view.presentScene(scene)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my previous games I've used a SKTransition to move to different scenes, and with that I could do some cool transitions like flip, fade and push.

I was wondering if this is the "correct" way of changing scenes when using the scene designer in Xcode? Or maybe I'm missing something.

Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do it like that with a loop, just to keep yourself from potentially running that presentation code more than once. Maybe setup your `touchesBegan` method with a guard statement

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Guard to just use the first touch
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
    if node.name == "WoodIcon" {
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "WoodScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you want to do a custom transition through code you can do something like this:

```
func customTransition() {

    // Wait three seconds then present a custom scene transition
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0)
    let block = SKAction.run {

        // Obviously use whatever scene you want, this is just a regular GameScene file with a size initializer
        let newScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "fileName")!
        newScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        let transitionAction = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        self.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transitionAction)

    }
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait, block]))

}
```

I wouldn't say there is a right or wrong way, just preference about how fancy you want the transition to look.